# ADAL SPFx getCachedUser is always null

Tags: adal, spfx

We have an SPFx web part working pretty well, but even if the user is already logged into Office 365 when they hit the page containing the SPFx web part - the getCachedUser object is always null. This forces a redirect for login, which auto-redirects back to our application page immediately.

Our original PoC with straight JavaScript never did this, but the SPFx web part always redirects on first hit.

Has anyone seen and fixed this behaviour? What should we be looking for in our Authentication wrapper?

Here's an example of our code:

```
import * as AuthenticationContext from 'adal-angular';
import '../WebPartAuthenticationContext';

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      detailModal: false,
      item: null,
      columns: [],
      rows: [],
      titleFilter: null,
      filterBy: 'givenName'
    };

    const config: IAdalConfig = {
      tenant: this.props.tenant,
      clientId: this.props.clientId,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin
    };
    config.webPartId = '<GUID>';
    config.popUp = false;
    config.callback = (error: any, token: string): void => {};
    this.authCtx = new AuthenticationContext(config);
    this.authCtx.handleWindowCallback();
    AuthenticationContext.prototype._singletonInstance = undefined;
}

private getRealItemsByAzureGraph(searchFor: string){
    var params = {
      'api-version': '1.6',
      '$filter': searchFor, 
      '$top' : '999'
    }; 
    var baseURL = 'https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?' + jquery.param(params);

    var user = this.authCtx.getCachedUser();
    if (user) {
      this.authCtx.acquireToken("https://graph.windows.net", (error, accessToken) => {
        if (error || !accessToken) { console.log(error); } 
        else {
          jquery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: baseURL,
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
              'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
          }).done((data) => {
            var res = [];
            data.value.forEach((itm) => {
              if (itm.surname && itm.mail && itm.givenName && this.notInKeywords(itm)){
                if (this.props.showGuestUsers) {
                  res.push(itm);
                } else {
                  if (itm.userType !== "Guest") {
                    res.push(itm);
                  }
                }
              }
            });
            this.setState(
              {
                rows: res,
              }
            );
          }).fail((err) => {
            console.log(err.responseText);
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.authCtx.login();
    }
}
```

This code (and the other supporting code) works great, we just can't get around the redirect even if the user is logged in. The getCachedUser method is always null / undefined.